# Why does PageSpeed differ in developer tools, website and Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, page-speed

I just tried Google PageSpeed Analysis in the developer tools, Google Analytics and the website itself (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights). Now, in each of them I get differing results (sometimes with a difference of 30 points!), which makes it seem unreliable. The FAQs discuss the difference to Webmaster Tools, but in particular the developer tools and website should give me the same results it says.

Why the difference?

Comment: When you say 30 points are you talking about the time it measures for download or for the score out of 100 that some of these tools report to you?

Comment: Same score out of 100

Answer (score 1):

All different tools to measure website speeds are merely to be used as rough data that can help you improve load times and user experience over time.

Consequently it's not surprising that even tools from one company are giving different numbers.

And then I've looked at GA load times a few times and noticed they are so rough that they are completely not usable.